# Difference between warm wishes and wishes?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases, phrase-choice

When should I use *Thanks! for your warm wishes* or *Thanks! for your wishes*?

As I understand it, *thanks! for your warm wishes* means that your wishes are taken heartily. Also, I can use *thanks! for your warm wishes* on my birthday occasion.

Is my understanding correct in this?

Comment: [tchrist's comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33583/can-i-say-that-thanks-for-the-bonhomie-wishes?lq=1#comment62943_33583) applies here, too.  You shouldn't put an exclamation point in the middle of your sentences like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Warm wishes" has connotations of "very friendly" or "with love".  It is an expression that you might see in a note between close friends or relatives.  In other words, the people who are likely to come to a modest birthday party.

"Kind wishes" is still very positive, but does not have the intimate connotations of "warm wishes".

"Wishes" is usually positive.

Comment: Can I say, thanks for the bonhomie wishes?

Comment: Not if you expect your audience to know what *bonhomie* means.

Comment: Related follow-up question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33583/can-i-say-that-thanks-for-the-bonhomie-wishes

Comment: what about "cold wishes"?

Comment: @mohit -- "Cold wishes" is not an idiomatic expression.  It seems like a cross between "cold-hearted" or "in cold blood", and the opposite of "warm wishes".  "Ice cold wishes" would mean "revenge fantasies", and "cold wishes" would probably also be very unpleasant.

Answer (score 6):

People would not say "Thanks for your wishes."  That's weird-sounding.  Maybe if you were being sarcastic?

> I wish you would die a painful death!
>
> [rolling eyes] *Thanks for your wishes.*

If someone said *"I wish I could be there with you so you don't have to go through that ordeal all by yourself."* some natural responses would be:

> Aw, thanks for saying so.
>
> Thanks for thinking of me.
>
> I appreciate the sentiment!

But *"Thanks for your wishes."* is stilted and incomplete-sounding.  And *"Thanks for your warm wishes."* is also awkward, but a bit less so because it doesn't carry the sarcastic edge.  (Similarly *"Thanks for your kind words."* is less weird than *"Thanks for your words."*)

Slightly more natural would be:

> Thanks for **the** warm wishes.

Because it emphasizes that the wishes were given to you and not somehow still in possession of the giver.  Think about getting a sweater for your birthday... you would not say *"Thanks for your comfortable sweater."*  It's yours now, isn't it?  You'd say *"Thanks for the comfortable sweater (that you gave me)."*

But if someone sends you feedback on something you might say:

> Thanks for your thoughts.

Because the thoughts do still "belong" to them, so the "your" is fitting in this case.