# Can I say that "Thanks! for the bonhomie wishes"

Tags: phrase-usage, vocabulary, noun-phrases

Is it right to say while distributing sweets on the b'day ocassion - "Thanks! for the bonhomie wishes"

Comment: You cannot put the exclamation mark where you have.  It should be “Thanks for your fond wishes!” instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As snailboat points it out, the word *bonhomie* is not normally used to convey the 'thanks!' for any wishes.

In your sentence, the word seems to be used as a *adjective*, whereas it's [actually a noun.](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/bonhomie)

> bonhomie - *a feeling of cheerful friendship*

Down there, the noun is used this way

> *There was a casual bonhomie between the actors at rehearsals.*

If you see your sentence and fit in this word there, it won't look natural.

In my opinion, you should keep it short and simple - **"Thanks for your birthday wishes."**

I assume that the sweet is distributed when someone wishes to a birthday boy/girl here.

---

Looking at your *comment* [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33579/difference-between-warm-wishes-and-wishes#33579), it seems that you are in search for a proper adjective to be put before the word 'wishes'; you need to emphasize it. Well, in that case, there could be many options including *warm, heartily, wonderful, lovely...and so on.*